AssertionError when running npx expo prebuild
I'm getting this error when I run npx expo prebuild. I've tried making multiple new projects, I'm usually given this error, and I've only ever gotten through the command once. That is, it happens even with fresh projects, so I have no idea how I might recreate it. Here's the error:
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: [android.dangerous]: withAndroidDangerousBaseMod: Project file "MainApplication" does not exist in android project for root "/Users/[me]/Documents/[03] Code/[app]"

Edit:
Here's the structure. MainApplication does exist and it's the one that's auto-generated by npx expo prebuild by default, which is why I don't understand how there's a probem.


Can you share the structure of your project? Does the MainApplication class exist?

Just edited with a screenshot of file structure and answering your questions.

I have same problem, did you manage to solve it?
